# How to configure custom domain name for Amazon ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

Amazon Elastic Container Repositories (ECR) have quite human-unfriendly URIs, like `99999999999.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`. Is it at all possible to configure custom domain name for an ECR?

Simplistic solution would be to create a CNAME record to point to the ECR URI, but this doesn't really work (SSL certificate doesn't match the domain name, passwords generated by `aws ecr get-login` don't pass, cannot push images tagged with custom domain name...).

Are there other options?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately, AWS does not support custom domain names for ECR. You'll have to make do with the auto-generated ones for now. There are 'hacks' about, which centre around Nginx proxies, but it really isn't worth the effort.

Comment: I think it should be worth it. If you change your server, then all your developers using docker will have to be notified of the new AWS generated domain name... this wastes time.

Comment: @IsaakEriksson Each to their own, but I don't like the sound of this method. If you do give it a try though, I'd be intrigued to know how it works out if you wouldn't mind commenting back here!

Comment: I gave the nginx hack a try, but it doesn't work. The connection works, however there is a checksum error from docker when you try to push.

Comment: Props for giving it a go

Comment: @IsaakEriksson Did you try this? https://itnext.io/enable-aws-elastic-container-registry-custom-domain-and-anonymous-access-over-private-network-123d07663709

Answer (score 5):

If you are using docker-compose, one way to get mitigate the ugly host portion of this is to use `ARG` in `Dockerfile` and define your host in `.env`.

derived/Dockerfile:

```
ARG REGISTRY_HOST
FROM ${REGISTRY_HOST}/namespace/base:latest
...
```

.env:

```
REGISTRY_HOST=99999999999.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.3"
services:

  base-service:
    image: ${REGISTRY_HOST}/namespace/base:latest
    build:
      context: base/

    ...

  derived-service:
    image: ${REGISTRY_HOST}/namespace/derived:latest
    build:
      context: derived/
      args:
        - REGISTRY_HOST=${REGISTRY_HOST}
...
```

The advantage of putting `${REGISTRY_HOST}` in the `image` declaration is that you can `docker-compose push base-service` and it will properly push the image to your ECS repo.

None of this is as clean as if AWS allowed custom hostnames for ECS repositories, but it's better than hardcoding that god-awful string in all your `Dockerfile`s. You could do this without docker-compose as well obviously but you'd have to define the build arg on the command line, something like `docker build --build-arg REGISTRY_HOST=99999999999.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com ...`

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to use `terraform`, the following project does an excellent job of providing a module for exactly this purpose: https://github.com/amancevice/terraform-aws-custom-ecr-domain