# Need an ECR Docker registry, presented behind a private domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-registry, amazon-ecr

I need to install a system and keep it updated trough Docker images into an institution that has  very rigid security rules. They demand that all domains that are to be set as exception to their firewall to be private and exclusive to our operation.

That means I cannot use  a docker registry  in a public domain, not even in AWS ECR as the domain  is not exclusive to our organization (for example 4556.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/erp:1.0 is not acceptable sicne ecr.ap-south.....aws.com is not exclusive to our organization). That said we do not want, if possible, to implement our very own Docker registry just for this deployment.

I could not find any explanation anywhere on how could I put that ECR behind My own  domain (even if registered in AWS). Does anyone  have any idea where I could figure pointers on how to do that?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50638998/how-to-configure-custom-domain-name-for-amazon-ecr#50642578

Comment: This is the way ECR works, it has certificates to their domainname, you can use a reverse proxy in front of the ECR with its own domain and certificate, but it's probably better to skip ECR and setup your own docker repository, it's not hard.

Comment: @sleepyhead Thanks. That is unfortunate, but thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to use Terraform, the following project does an excellent job of providing a module for exactly this purpose: https://github.com/amancevice/terraform-aws-custom-ecr-domain